# floating point exception in c program

Tags: c

I am having floating point exception in the following code .

```
int heavy_decimal_count ( int A, int B )        
{        
 char * markup = "Heavy";    
 int i , value;   
 int tempA = A;   
 int tempB = B;    
 int reminder = 0;    
 int sum = 0;     
 float average = 0.00;     
 int counter = 0;    
 if( (tempA < 0) || ( tempB <0 )||( B < A ) )    
 {    
    printf(" Error -> Numbers are negative or B is less than A");     
    return 0;     
 }    
 for (  i = A ; i <= B ; i++)     
 {    
     value = i;     
     while( value > 0 )    
     {    
        printf(" the value is %d ", value );     
        counter += counter;     
        reminder = value % 10;      
        value /= 10;    
        sum += reminder;     
        average =  sum/counter ;     

    }     
    if( average > 7.0 )    
            printf(" %d \t  avg= %f\t %s\t" ,i , average , markup);   
        else     
            printf(" %d \t  avg=%f\t " ,i , average );     
}     
return 0;      
 }
```

Comment: Use a debugger and at least figure out where it happens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Despite the name, a "floating point exception" actually happens when you `/` or `%` an integer by `0`. My guess is that it happens here:

```
average =  sum/counter ;
```

because `counter` is still `0`. I think you meant

```
counter += counter;
```

to be

```
counter += 1;
```

Also, you might want to change the division to

```
average =  (float)sum/counter ;
```

so it can happen as a fraction value rather than an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are dividing by zero in the following line

> average =  sum/counter ;

counter is initially, definied as zero;

> int counter = 0;

and updated here;

> counter += counter;  // counter remains zero....

did you mean to update counter by one instead? e.g.

> counter += 1;